# Why there is no __dict__ attribute in pyodbc.Row class?

Tags: python, pyodbc

Why there is no `__dict__` attribute in a `pyodbc.Row` instance? `__dict__` is a built-in attribute in every Python object; if it was specifically removed by developers, what for?

Comment: Perhaps it uses `__slots__`, for the reasons outlined in e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/472000/3001761. **Edit**: or because [it's not a Python class, it's C++](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/blob/master/src/row.cpp#L17).

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thank you. Those two facts explain this solution very good.